# Azure Pipeline python script environment variables

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a python script which it has 2 line of code where I have my username and password and I don't want to push them to GitHub for obvious reasons, but they are important for my azure DevOps pipeline to run successfully. Following some documentation, I set in my python script the òs.environ.get` to be able to retrieve the value from a environment variable.

my code looks like this.

```
import os

usernameot = os.environ.get('USERNAMEOT')
passwordot = os.environ.get('PASSWORDOT')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='visible-lg'] input#signInFormUsername"))).send_keys(usernameot)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='visible-lg'] input#signInFormPassword"))).send_keys(passwordot)
```

This was the first step and after this problem started. I have a azure pipeline that looks like this.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job: Configuration
        steps:
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.8'
              addToPath: true
          - script: |
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip install selenium
              printenv
          - task: Pythonscript@0
            inputs:
              scriptSource: 'filePath'
              scriptPath: './script1.py'
            env:
              USERNAMEOT: $(usernameot)
              PASSWORDOT: $(passwordot)

      - job: Mailinator
        dependsOn: Configuration
        steps:
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.x'
              addToPath: true
          - script: |
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip install selenium
          - task: Pythonscript@0
            inputs:
              scriptSource: 'filePath'
              scriptPath: './script2.py'
```

I tried to pass the environment variable in all the ways that I know.

The pipeline above is the latest one, I tried to store the variables in azure DevOps pipeline but it fails as my python script doesn't find the `username` value in the environment variables.
I tried to use GitHub secret and environment but it fails because it doesn't reconize the key `secret.USERNAME`

Can please any of you help me to understand how I can set a environment variable on my pipeline vm during the run time?

EDIT:
I tried all the solutions advice by bazetto (thank you so much for your help) but still facing the same issue.

As you can see, the pipeline return the correct values for my variables, but those are not passed to the python script.
Even if the error point to the css selector no found, I am pretty sure that the web driver is working because before to get to the username and password, there are different buttons to click etc. So what is my guess, is that when it comes to pass the username and password, as the variable does not get read from my configuration, the selenium script timeout.

Any advice about this please?

UPDATE:
I did some update to the pipeline and my python script.

In python I am getting the username and configuration from a json file that get populated during the runtime, and I am feeding those variables values to my script.

following another advice, I set the variables on each step of my  pipeline, but yet I am getting an error, as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\script1.py", line 49, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='visible-lg'] input#signInFormUsername"))).send_keys(usernameot)
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.8.10\x64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message


##[error]The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.11/x64/bin/python' failed with exit code 1
```

I really don't understand what I am doing wrong, I think I understand all the steps and what everyone is suggesting, but I might have miss something in my scripts and configuration for sure

Comment: You might face issues related to enviroment variables due to admin privileges.

We usually create a 'config.json' file to run the selenium tests. And, the app reads that file rather than the env variables. Also, we have a shell script step in the pipeline to populate these variables.

Comment: Do you mind to give me an example of the config. Json please? That would help me to understand better my error and try to follow your advice. Thank you so much and sorry for asking this but I am really struggling

Comment: Added as an awnser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define variables in Azure DevOps you have an option to mark them as secrets.

[image]

Above `username` is not a secrets, and password is. In this case not-secret variables are mapped to environment variables.

What you can check with this:

```yaml
steps:
- script: env | sort
  displayName: 'Display env variables'
```

```
PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/vsts/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/usr/share/rust/.cargo/bin:/home/vsts/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/vsts/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PIPELINE_WORKSPACE=/home/vsts/work/1
PIPX_BIN_DIR=/opt/pipx_bin
PIPX_HOME=/opt/pipx
.
.
.
TASK_DISPLAYNAME=Display env variables
TF_BUILD=True
USER=vsts
USERNAME=someusername
VCPKG_INSTALLATION_ROOT=/usr/local/share/vcpkg
```

However, there is still a way how to map them to env variables. There is explicit mapping like below:

```yaml
- bash: |
    echo "Using the mapped env var for this task works and is recommended: $MY_MAPPED_PASSWORD"
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_PASSWORD: $(password)
```

But this is limited to task scope. So you can use this env variable only in this task. If you need this in more tasks, then you need to repeat that env mapping accross every task.

So if you have both `username` and `password` defined as secret you need to mapp both values:

```yaml
          - task: Pythonscript@0
            inputs:
              scriptSource: 'filePath'
              scriptPath: './script1.py'
            env:
              PASSWORD: $(password) 
              USERNAME: $(username)
```

And if you see `***` in logs this is masking which Azure DevOps does to hide your secret if it appears anywhere in logs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try this step but there is some thing that is confusing me. In azure DevOps portal, if I open the pipeline and click on `run pipeline` in the tab that opens, there is a link to set the variables there, but also, if I click on `edit pipeline` on the top right I have the `variables` to be set. what are the difference between those 2 because they are not related to each other

Comment: First one give you a way to override variable for specific run, or define variable for specific run. The former is linked to a pipeline definition so by default each runs get those variables.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I tried your approach, but still the same error. I did update my post with my original code and I have no idea what I am doing wrong at this point :( thank you very much for any help, you have no idea how grateful I am

Comment: My answer will work for you if you fetch values `os.environ["PASSWORD"]` as this.

Comment: I tired (updated also my post) with os.environ but I am still getting the same error. Its failing to fetch the variables

Comment: I followed step by step your raccomandation and I set the os.environ.get, as you can see in my updated topic. in my python script I printed the usernameot and passwordot and they are returning correctly the values, but yet the line of python that should use that variable, it does fail as usual.

Comment: But what you get when you run this script on your local workstation with those values?

Comment: in my local computer, if I set environment variables and run my script, it works just fine. no problem at all at that stage. this script fails only on the pipeline

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time. The error was not related to the pipeline or environment variable, but it was due to the screen resolution. I will give you the bounty because you helped me to solve the main issue

Answer (score 1):

You might face issues related to environment variables due to admin privileges.

My suggestion is to replace it with a file, like

config.json

```json
{
   "username": "",
   "password": ""
}
```

in your pipeline, add a step to populate it:

```yaml
  - stage: temp

    jobs:
      - job: temp
        displayName: temp
        
        variables:
          - name: USERNAME
            value: "USER1"

          - name: PASSWORD
            value: "MYPWD1"
        
        steps:
          - checkout: self
        
          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: "Set configuration"
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                #read config
                $config = Get-Content (Get-Item .\config.json) -Raw -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json

                #set the credentials
                $config.username = "$(USERNAME)" #assuming that you already have it
                $config.password = "$(PASSWORD)" #assuming that you already have it


                #update the file
                $config | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content .\config.json

          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: "show configuration"
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                #debug
                cat config.json
```

The configuration step must show something like:
[image: show configuration]

in your python app something like:

```py
import json

f = open('config.json',)
data = json.load(f)

username = data['username']
password = data['password']

#debug
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried you advice and approach, but I am still getting the same error. The weird thing is, if I run your code locally, I am able to see the username and password and everything works fine. So I tried to print the username and password I have in my script during the run time..and nothing gets printed.they are totally ignored

Comment: Are you using secret variables to store your data? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

Comment: Yes in devops portal pipelines, under variables I am setting the variables there. In fact I am able to echo the values of those variables(for debugging) and they are correct. But for some reason, they don't get injdcted to python script.

Comment: I've added 2 steps for debugging, the first one in PowerShell just to ensure that the file has been replaced and the second one in Python.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time mate. I tried the debugging you suggested and in fact, the `cat .\config.json` it fails with error `no such file or directory`. The pipeline and the config.json are at the same level.

Comment: Fixed the problem. I had to remove the `.\` . Interesting fact, the `print(data)` return empty values from `config.json`..this is the result of the print`{'username': '', 'password': ''}` empty values

Comment: thanks, I've fixed the example. Also, I added a print about the show configuration step output. If you can't see the output might be an issue in your variables

Comment: The reason why I was not able to see the config.json is because my pipelines had `jobs`.. and the `cat config.json` was on a different job, which I assume was running on a different worker and not able to retrieve the info from the previous one. I set them as tasks inside the same job and now I can see the output. But still, python script fails to use those credentials to login. This is the first time I am facing this issue honestly